# SwiftUI data flow and UI update for foreign model object with changing values but same id

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui

I have an array of objects ("things") of some third party library that I want to display in a SwiftUI View.
These "Thing" objects are Identifiable and Hashable by an id, but when reloading a new set of Things, their content may have changed (let's say a "status" or a "text" of that Thing, although it is the same Thing again). So the id keeps the same, but the content of a Thing can change.
Problem is, that SwiftUI doesn't update the UI when I get a new array of Things. I assume this is because the Things are "identified" as the same Things again by their id.
I can not change Thing, because it is from a third party library.

Now I simply wrapped Thing into another class and suddenly it works! But I want to understand *why* this works, and if it is defined behaviour and not just coincidence or "luck".

Can anybody explain what happens here behind the scene? Especially what is the main difference between DirectThingView and WrappedThingView that causes SwiftUI to update the UI for the latter and not for the former?

Or are the any suggestions how to solve this problem in a better way?

Here is sample code that shows everything:
It displays the Things in two columns; first column uses the DirectThingView and second column uses the WrappedThingView. If you hit the "Reload" button, the things array gets filled with changed Things, but only the UI of the right column correctly updates the values; the left column always stays at its initial state.

```
//
//  TestView.swift
//
//  Created by Manfred Schwind on 10.07.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 mani.de. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

// The main model contains an array of "Things",
// every Thing has an id and contains a text.
// For testing purposes, every other time a Thing gets instantiated, its text contains either "A" or "B".
// Problem here: the "current" text of a Thing with the same id can change, when Things are reloaded.
class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var things = [Thing(id: 1), Thing(id: 2), Thing(id: 3)]
}

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = TestViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 30) {
            HStack (spacing: 40) {
                // We try to display the current Thing array in the UI

                // The views in the first column directly store the Thing:
                // Problem here: the UI does not update for changed Things ...
                VStack {
                    Text("Direct")
                    ForEach(self.viewModel.things, id: \.self) { thing in
                        DirectThingView(viewModel: thing)
                    }
                }
                // The views in the second column store the Thin wrapped into another class:
                // In this case, the problem magically went away!
                VStack {
                    Text("Wrapped")
                    ForEach(self.viewModel.things, id: \.self) { thing in
                        WrappedThingView(viewModel: thing)
                    }
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                // change the Thing array in the TestViewModel, this causes the UI to update:
                self.viewModel.things = [Thing(id: 1), Thing(id: 2), Thing(id: 3)]
            }) {
                Text("Reload")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DirectThingView: View {
    // first approach just stores the passed Thing directly internally:
    private let viewModel: Thing

    init(viewModel: Thing) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.viewModel.text)
    }
}

struct WrappedThingView: View {
    // second approach stores the passed Thing wrapped into another Object internally:
    private let viewModel: WrappedThing

    init(viewModel: Thing) {
        // take the Thing like in the first approach, but internally store it wrapped:
        self.viewModel = WrappedThing(childModel: viewModel)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.viewModel.childModel.text)
    }

    // If type of WrappedThing is changed from class to struct, then the problem returns!
    private class WrappedThing {
        let childModel: Thing
        init(childModel: Thing) {
            self.childModel = childModel
        }
    }

}

// Thing has do be Identifiable and Hashable for ForEach to work properly:
class Thing: Identifiable, Hashable {

    // Identifiable:
    let id: Int

    // The text contains either "A" or "B", in alternating order on every new Thing instantiation
    var text: String

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        struct Holder {
            static var flip: Bool = false
        }
        self.text = Holder.flip ? "B" : "A"
        Holder.flip = !Holder.flip
    }

    // Hashable:
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.id)
    }

    // Equatable (part of Hashable):
    public static func == (lhs: Thing, rhs: Thing) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
#endif
```

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for myself. The problem is the implementation of Equatable of Thing here. As implemented above, an old and a new version of the same Thing (but with different content) are considered equal. But SwiftUI distincts between "identity" and "equality" and this has to be properly implemented.

In the code above, Identifiable and Hashable are OK, but Equatable has to be changed to be more precise. So e.g. this fixes the problem:

```
// Thing has do be Identifiable and Hashable for ForEach to work properly:
class Thing: Identifiable, Hashable {

    // Identifiable:
    let id: Int

    // The text contains either "A" or "B", in alternating order on every new Thing instantiation
    var text: String

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        struct Holder {
            static var flip: Bool = false
        }
        self.text = Holder.flip ? "B" : "A"
        Holder.flip = !Holder.flip
    }

    // Hashable:
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        // we are lazy and just use the id here, "collisions" are then separated by func ==
        hasher.combine(self.id)
    }

    // Equatable (part of Hashable):
    public static func == (lhs: Thing, rhs: Thing) -> Bool {
        // We are lazy again (in reality Thing has many properties) and we consider
        // two Things to be the equal ONLY when they point to the same address.
        // So we get the "same but different" semantic that we want, when we are
        // getting a new version of the Thing.
        // (Same in the sense of identity, different in the sense of equality)
        return lhs === rhs
    }
}
```